# hide specific divs after clicking on other div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I am quite new in jQuery.

I have a html code as below which is generated on the fly and added to my page:

```
<div class="outstandingcallback">
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
</div>
<div class="outstandingcallback">
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
</div>
    ......
```

I need to hide one of them when I click on the other one.
I used following jQuery but I am not sure how can I hide the div element.

```
    $('.outstandingcallback').bind('click', function () {
                var selectdCallItemID = $(".callItemID", this).html();


                var myHtmlCode = $('#CallBacks').html();

                $('' + myHtmlCode + '').find('div').each(function () {
                    var thisCallID = $(".callItemID", this).html();

                    if (thisCallID == selectdCallItemID ) {
                        alert("test");
                        $('' + myHtmlCode + '').find(this).hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

I am not sure about the following part:

```
    $('' + myHtmlCode + '').find(this).hide();
```

Comment: Create jsFidel demo pls

Comment: try this one `$('.outstandingcallback').hide();`

Comment: Where is callItemID found?

Comment: Here is the JSFidel page : http://jsfiddle.net/xT5Ge/1/
I have pasted my codes there, but I dont know why its not working there!

Comment: @7alhashmi I want to hide ONE of them (The selected one), not both!

Comment: `$(".outstandingcallback:first").show();`

Comment: ok, its means on which you clicked then it should hide .

Comment: @7alhashmi please read the thread completely! There are not just two items. As they are generated on the fly, therefore FIRST and LAST can not be used here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.siblings()` to find other elems at same level:

because *`which is generated on the fly and added to my page` use `.on`* and delegate the event to the closest existing parent or `document`

```
 $(document).on('click', '.outstandingcallback', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.outstandingcallback').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/xjew8/)

```
 $('.outstandingcallback').bind('click', function () {
     $('.outstandingcallback').hide(); 
     $(this).show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function doAnimation()
 {
    $("#secondDiv").toggle(300);
 }
  </script>


 <div id='firstDiv' onclick='doAnimation()'></div>
 <div id='secondDiv' ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".outstandingcallback:first").click()) {
    $(".outstandingcallback:first").show();
    $(".outstandingcallback:last").hide();
} else if ($(".outstandingcallback:last").click()) {
    $(".outstandingcallback:first").hide();
    $(".outstandingcallback:last").show();
}
```

Comment: As I said, These are being generated on the fly, so no one knows how many of them will be generated and on which one you click!

Comment: var outstanding=$(".outstandingcallback");
 for(var i=0;i<outstanding.length;i++)
 {  
    $(outstanding[i]).attr("id","child-"+i);
 }

Comment: generate scripts dynamically is not an option!

Answer (score 0):

to simply hide the unclicked div all you need is this:

```
 $(function(){
    $('.outstandingcallback').on('click', function () {
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
})
```